# JW player not working on Internet Explorer with flash, hls/rtmp and fancybox

Tags: fancybox, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We're having an issue with JW player. When opening the player in a Fancybox the player gets loaded but the play button is sort of disabled.
The strange thing is that when i double click on the player the video will start playing in full screen.

These things are working:

- Outside a fancybox.
- Inside a fancybox without hls/rtmp streaming.
- Inside a fancybox with a flash version lower then the latest v.15

When we combine these 3 things the video won't play.

Comment: A link to your site is going to be needed for anyone to have any hope of diagnosing this issue.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: is your fancybox video(s) included in a fancybox gallery?